# Multiple data-attribute filteration using input checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want a jQuery function that filters a set of `data-attributes`.

In my HTML structure I have a number of list items and there attributes are:

`data-offer` and `data-subcat` these two will be used to filter out the items using multiple input check boxes.

So far I have this jQuery which is performing filtration but not as I want it to be.

```
$(".cs-widget-content").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    $(".five-column > li.column").hide();
    $(".cs-widget-content").find("input:checked").each(function (i, el) {
        $(".five-column > li.column").filter('[data-offer="' + el.id + '"]').show();
    });

    $(".cs-widget-content").find("input:checked").each(function (j, el) {
        $(".five-column > li.column").filter('[data-subcat="' + el.id + '"]').show();
    });

});
```

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/devyaqoob/k62kxm0x/1/)

**Solution I want:**

1. All the data should be load on Page load (Which is working).
2. The inputs filter for both data-attributes should work together (e.g when an input is checked for `data-offer` it will show that data and if the `data-subcat` is checked it will show up the data for this attribute as well, within the previous checked of `data-offer`.
3. When any of the input is unChecked, the data should be visible back.

looking forward for your help.

*Thank you*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate through the products rather than the filters and decide for each whether it should be displayed.

```
var filter1HasChecked = $("[data-filter=1]:checked").length;
var filter2HasChecked = $("[data-filter=2]:checked").length;

$("ul.products li").each(function(i,v){
    var $this = $(this);

    if((!filter1HasChecked || $("#" + $this.data("offer")).is(":checked"))
       && (!filter2HasChecked || $("#" + $this.data("subcat")).is(":checked"))){
       $this.show();
    }        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/k62kxm0x/4/

This sort of operation would become costly with 100s of items, but then I would suggest some server-side filtering using AJAX, or perhaps implementation of a front-end framework such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Curt, i'm going to test this on my production page i'll get back to you with results. And I have never used AngularJs so i have no idea about this Framework.

Comment: Curt, your jQuery is perfectly working as i wanted :) just a small issue on my end though, when i filter a lot of items they gets hidden from there positions Which is fine but the layout seems to be breaking. is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: @yaqoob This sounds like a different issue perhaps with your CSS styling. I would raise a seperate question with the exact issue if you need help

Comment: Alright, i'll post it separately. thanks alot for the help :) really appreciated the super fast fix.